# Changing the appearance of org-mode “hidden contents” ellipsis

Tags: org-mode, outline

In `org-mode`, when the contents of a subtree are hidden you see something like

```
* Some tree
  :PROPERTIES:...

** Another One...
```

Is there a way to change those `...` to something else? I'd like to use something shorter like a utf-8 ellipsis or a rounded arrow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just customise the variable `org-ellipsis`.  Something like

```
(setq org-ellipsis "…")
```

Comment: Awesome, I've set it to `"⮷"`. I'm sure I'll get sick of it soon but right now it looks sweet.

Comment: If you want to change the appearance but not the symbol, you can set `org-ellipsis` to a face instead of a string.

Comment: @erikstokes Is there a way to do both (i.e. change the face and the symbol)?

Comment: @ph0t0nix Not a way as easy as just setting a variable.  `org-ellipsis` only lets you customize one.  You can hack the display table as in the other answers to set the face and the symbol.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the characters more generally for selective display with:

```
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 
                        'selective-display (string-to-vector " ◦◦◦ ")) ; or whatever you like
```

I've been using these characters because I find them easier to see than the periods, and yet not too distracting.  To each their own, though.

I got this from the [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode): look for the section on "Customizing Outline ellipsis" for more details.

Comment: Doh!  Stefan beat me to it.  I'll leave it up for the Wiki link.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, instead of setting it only for Org, I do it globally with:

```
(unless standard-display-table
  (setq standard-display-table (make-display-table)))
(when (fboundp 'make-glyph-code)
  (set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 4
                          (vector (make-glyph-code ?…)
                                  (make-glyph-code ?…))))
```