# Set face of outline ellipsis?

Tags: faces, outline-mode

**Q:** how do I change the *face* of the outline ellipsis?

When working with outlines, the (customizable) ellipsis indicates when a section is folded and there is hidden text, eg:

```
* A heading...
** A subheading...
*** A subsubheading...
```

The ellipsis is customizable via the `selective-display` slot of the `display-table`, eg:

```
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 
                        'selective-display 
                        (string-to-vector "!!!"))
```

Which gets us to:

```
* A heading!!!
** A subheading!!!
*** A subsubheading!!!
```

(No, I'm not actually using exclamation points, it's just an example.)

However, what I'd like to do is *customize the ellipsis so that it **takes the same face as the outline header** it is on*.  How would one do that?

PS: Note that the [EmacsWiki `outline-mode` node](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode) has a couple of suggestions for setting the face, but neither seem to work (at least for me).

PPS: A [related thread on the `org-ellipsis`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10981/changing-the-appearance-of-org-mode-hidden-contents-ellipsis) does not explicitly handle the faces issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q**:   "*However, what I'd like to do is customize the ellipsis so that it takes the same face as the outline header it is on. How would one do that?*"

**A**:   This cannot be done using the `buffer-display-table`.  It's an all or nothing type of deal -- i.e., a change to the `buffer-display-table` affects everything in the buffer, not merely a particular heading.  It is possible to create a different custom overlay for each heading, but it may not be very efficient -- in that case, the display slot 4 would not be used.

---

Here is an example of what is going on behind the scenes when setting the face for the ellipsis in either `outline-mode` or `org-mode`.  The display engine of Emacs has built-in support for text with invisible property at the end of the line, which can be visualized via the `buffer-display-table`.  For more information about this special slot, type:  `M-x describe-variable RET buffer-display-table RET`

```lisp
(let ((display-table
        (if buffer-display-table
          buffer-display-table
          (make-display-table))))
  (unless buffer-display-table
    (setq buffer-display-table display-table))
  (set-display-table-slot display-table 4
    (vconcat (mapcar (lambda (c)
      (make-glyph-code c 'font-lock-keyword-face)) "..."))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in your PPS, you can set `org-ellipsis` to a face. Looking at `org-ellipsis` docstring in `org.el`, it says `org-ellipsis` can be set to a face:

```el
(defcustom org-ellipsis nil
  "The ellipsis to use in the Org-mode outline.
When nil, just use the standard three dots.
When a string, use that string instead.
When a face, use the standard 3 dots, but with the specified face.
The change affects only Org-mode (which will then use its own display table).
Changing this requires executing \\[org-mode] in a buffer to become
effective."
  :group 'org-startup
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Default" nil)
         (face :tag "Face" :value org-warning)
         (string :tag "String" :value "...#")))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about `outline-mode` in general rather than only `org-mode`.  I'm also asking about a variable face (ie, setting the ellipsis to use a different face depending on which depth of the outline it's in.)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer specifying it is only org-mode related.

Comment: I had tried changing the `org-ellipsis` face but it didn't seem to do anything - I didn't realize you had to set an `org-ellipsis` variable also!